# subprocess terminating a PowerShell Script before completion

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell

Only in Python 3.7 using subprocessing methods `run`, `Popen` etc. or even using `os.system()` The PowerShell Script I'm calling seems to terminate before completion.  I have a much more complex script, but I have been able to simplify both the Python script and PowerShell script to exhibit the issue.  The PowerShell Script is also shown below.

Here is the Python code:

''' subprocess truncates output '''

```
import subprocess       # subprocess library

p = subprocess.run("powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:/PS/testAquire.ps1",
                   shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print("stdout:", p.stdout)
print("stderr:", p.stderr)
```

This is the Python script output showing no errors:

```
stdout: b''
stderr: None
```

This is the **entire** contents of the `result.txt` file after execution using the Python script above.

```
Directory: C:\windows\system32\drivers


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name

----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                   d-----        4/12/2018   5:15 AM                en-US
d-----        4/12/2018   5:15 AM                UMDF

-a----        1/19/2017   5:43 AM           3301 1028_Dell_INS_24-7459.mrk
-a----        4/11/2018   7:34 PM          29696 afunix.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:34 PM        3440660 gm.dls
-a----        4/11/2018   7:34 PM            646 gmreadme.txt
-a----        9/12/2015   4:59 AM          18720 IntelMEFWVer.dll
```

This is the PowerShell Script

```
<#
.synopsis
Sample script to demonstrate unusual results when called from Python 3.7
#>

Get-ChildItem c:/windows/system32/drivers/ |  Format-Table | Out-File c:/PS/result.txt -Encoding ascii
```

This is the normal output of the script when run from the PowerShell Command or when using Python 2.7 to launch the PowerShell script.

```
Directory: C:\windows\system32\drivers


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name

----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                         d-----        4/11/2018   7:38 PM                DriverData
d-----        8/15/2018   5:33 PM                en-US
d-----        5/30/2018   9:31 AM                etc
d-----       11/14/2018   5:32 PM                UMDF
d-----       12/10/2018   5:50 PM                wd

-a----        1/19/2017   5:43 AM           3301 1028_Dell_INS_24-7459.mrk

-a----        4/11/2018   7:33 PM         237568 1394ohci.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:33 PM         107416 3ware.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:33 PM         654232 acpi.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:33 PM          20480 AcpiDev.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:33 PM         127904 acpiex.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:33 PM          12800 acpipagr.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:33 PM          14848 acpipmi.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:33 PM          13824 acpitime.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:33 PM        1135520 adp80xx.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:34 PM         626592 afd.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:34 PM          39424 afunix.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:34 PM         108032 agilevpn.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:34 PM         254464 ahcache.sys
-a----        9/24/2015   5:17 AM         109200 aksdf.sys
-a----        9/24/2015   5:17 AM         205528 aksfridge.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:33 PM         181760 amdk8.sys

... ... I reduced the output for brevity ...

-a----        4/11/2018   7:34 PM          33184 WppRecorder.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:34 PM          23040 ws2ifsl.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:33 PM          23040 WSDPrint.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:33 PM          25088 WSDScan.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:34 PM         125440 WUDFPf.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:34 PM         264192 WUDFRd.sys
-a----        6/15/2018  12:44 AM         295424 xboxgip.sys
-a----        4/11/2018   7:33 PM          46592 xinputhid.sys
```

I should note I have tried dozens of methods to launch the script with the same results.

Comment: I just ran the code on my pc with python 3.x and had no problems. It completed the task as requested. This is something to do with your configuration or pc (either your powershell, your python installation or something else). I can't say what exactly, but if I couldn't recreate the issue it's something to do with your pc

Comment: Thanks yuvi, I'm curious, were you running Python 3.7.2?  I'm wondering if I should downgrade to Python 3.6 or even 3.5 and try this.

Comment: yeah I used python 3.5 I think. Maybe it is a bug with python, I'd suggest you [send them a bug report about it](https://docs.python.org/3/bugs.html#using-the-tracker)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run the subprocess without using a shell? Like so:

```
subprocess.run(
  ["powershell", "-ExecutionPolicy", "ByPass", "-File", "C:/PS/testAquire.ps1"],
  shell=False,
)
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to make use of the PowerShell, why not use it to redirect the output into the destination file (simple add a redirection to the end of the command; `... > c:/output.file`)

Comment: Thanks, dr1fter, no joy same results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for looking into this.  I uninstalled Python 3.7.2 and then installed 3.6.8 and it works as designed.  I have not determined if the problem was 3.7.2 or something to do with the installation.  I will investigate.

Again, thanks for all your help and suggestions.